# Cardinality of $\mathbb R/\mathord{\sim}$ when the equivalence classes are measurable

Tags: measure-theory, logic, set-theory

Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$ such that each equivalence class is Lebesgue measurable.

Can we prove that we do **not** have
$$
\operatorname{card}(\mathbb N) < \operatorname{card}(\mathbb R/\mathord{\sim}) < \operatorname{card}(\mathbb R)\ ?
$$
(By $\operatorname{card}(S)$ I denote the cardinality of $S$.)

---

[Thanks to arjafi their edit! arjafi removed the logic tag. I put it back not to start an edit war, but because of the connection with the continuum hypothesis, which is usually considered as belonging to mathematical logic.]

Comment: What do you mean by measurable? Lebesgue-, Borel-, or something else?

Comment: @drhab - I mean Lebesgue measurable, but if you have an answer (or just comments) about the Borel case, I'd be most interested... I'll edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No --- on the contrary, such a $\sim$ will exist if and (assuming AC) only if the continuum hypothesis is false:

Suppose there is *some* set of reals of cardinality strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak c$.

Since the reals are in bijective correspondence with the Cantor set (which has measure zero), this means that there is an intermediate-cardinality subset of the Cantor set. Being a null set, this is measurable, so its complement is measurable too.

Now make each point in the intermediate-cardinality set its own equivalence class and lump everything else into a single additional equivalence class.

Comment: Thanks! My question is: can one prove, using only ZFC, that the quotient in question does not violate CH. Does your post answer this question?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Yes, my post answers that: If we _could_ prove that no such quotient can have intermediate cardinality, then in combination with my construction this would amount to _a proof of CH_ by contradiction. But we know that CH is independent of ZFC, so this is only possible if ZF(C) is inconsistent.

Comment: OK. One more question: It seems to me your answer implies that CH is equivalent to the inexistence of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$ of intermediate cardinality, and I thought one can prove in ZFC that such subsets don't exist. What am I missing?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: What ZFC proves (if I remember correctly) is that there can't be intermediate-cardinality subsets of $\mathbb R$ _with nonzero Lebesgue measure_. But the one that appears in this argument is null.

Comment: I think you're right. I was making a confusion. Thanks for having answered my question and my silly comments!

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard By inner regularity of Lebesgue measure, any measurable set of positive measure contains a compact subset of positive measure. And one can prove $\mathsf{CH}$ for closed sets without any appeal to choice or additional axioms.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo - Thank you very much for such a useful comment!

Comment: Regardless of CH, a closed set of positive measure must be uncountable, and every closed uncountable set  of reals has the cardinal of the reals.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: That seems to be exactly Andrés's comment.